# Deploying app that requires root privileges to run

Tags: linux, root, deb, electron

I'm deploying an app (built with Electron) as a deb file, and I'd like the user to install it and run it with root privileges only, like the way GParted does (retrieving them on boot event and execute anything needed without asking them again).

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this? I am not a Linux dev, but I'd guess that there is documentation available for how you tell an application that it must run as root on the target system.

Answer (score 1):

You give us so little information but I will do my best.

1. ALL DEB PACKAGES REQUIRE ROOT to install so that part is a no-brainer.
2. Have the installation script set-user-bit and change the app's owner to root.

This should get you rolling.  If you want it to run on boot event, you are talking about a service and not an application (even though they are really the same thing) and this gets into the world of systemd (which is a very different question).. in this case, you would need your deb script to create .service files and the accounts to run under and queue them to run before or after any given service in the startup code.

If I wasn't clear, (I often ramble nonsense), please let me know where I can help.